# Jade Templates: Make an image a link

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

So in HTML i'd do something like this:

```
<a href="www.something.com">
    <img src="my/machine">
</a>
```

to make the image into a link. But I want to do the same for Jade. I was reading through the docs [here](http://jade-lang.com/reference/attributes/) but nothing relating to what I want. Help please? Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you're doing is nesting elements.  Nesting just requires new lines and a tab per nest level.

**Jade:**

```
a(href='www.something.com')
    img(src='my/machine')
```

Comment: doesnt work for me. and their documentation site also doesn't work, what is going on?

Comment: Works for putting inline svg onto a button too!

Answer (score 0):

Use `img(src= someExpr)` where someExpr will be evaluated to the path to your image.